# How do I format a XML file/output of an XQuery expression?

Tags: xml, xquery

After exceuting a xquery expression, the output is all 'together'. How do I add a newline or space inbetween elements of an xquery.

Is it through this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
```

If so, where do I put it within the xquery expression?

So I get:

```
<a><b>asdasdasd</b></a>
```

I want:

```
<a>
    <b>asdasdasd<b>
<a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That layout is usually done on windows with a built in XSLT provided with MSXML.

so you can apply it to the result of your XQuery (if teh resukt is valid xml !) 
Rember the output is HTML.

Last I looked the xsl was in one of the msxml dlls as a resource and called DefaultSS.xsl

If this is just for display, another way is
to save the output to a temporary file.

Add a webbrowser control and then navigate to the file.

If you don't like the idea of the file, then HTMLDocument is possibility, it's not pretty though.

Answer (score 1):

The output or serialization specifications described by W3C ( http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/ ) apply to both XSLT and XQuery. The difference is that it is well known how to use that in XSLT (the `xsl:output` instruction), whereas it hasn't been incorporated like that in the XQuery 1.0 specification. Most implementations provided custom extension to support it though. You would be looking for an `indent="yes"` property.

If you could share with us which XQuery implementation you are using, we could provided more details on how to enforce indentation.